# Kafka spark integration

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am building one application where I will get streaming data(csv) from kafka and write it to hdfs .Data will be comma separated but number of fields is not fixed . Since data structure of the file is not fixed I am not able to apply schema structure in spark streaming .

```
Data format:
A
B,C,D
A,B,C,D
```

My aim is to write this data as csv to hdfs using spark streaming .

So far I have tried Using below snippet I am able to write as json :

```
for msg in consumer:
  data = msg.value
  if data:
    data_json =json.loads(json.dumps(data,ensure_ascii=False,indent=1),encoding='utf-8')
    data_df=sqlContext.read.json(sc.parallelize([data_json]))
    data_df.write.mode('append').json(hdfs_path)
    consumer.commit()
```

I am using spark 1.6 and with python 2.7 . Any leads will be helpful .

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of fields that will be present in data?

Comment: @mayankagrawal yeah that information will be given

Comment: Can you show me a sample of the `json` you are getting in `data`?

Comment: @mayankagrawal data is coming in csv format as given the OP. but the number of field  can be maximum 150 .

Comment: You can add `None` elements in the json for those fields which are absent in each row.